# Login using Sorcery and OAuth - NameError

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, google-oauth, sorcery

I'm trying to build a foundation on which to start my projects in Rails 4 that require Sorcery for session control as well as OAuth support for Google (and eventually Facebook and Github). I'm fairly new to the dev scene and find myself in a constant struggle with Sorcery.

I want to be able to choose between logging in via OAuth, or creating a user in the standard fashion, and then having them redirect to the root post-login.

Currently, I'm getting an error of :

> NameError at /users/1 undefined local variable or method `set_user' for #UsersController:0x007fbb0b237f80

I've scoured the net for answers to this problem, but I can't seem to track down a solution.

Any help on this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Repo can be found at https://github.com/cryophobic/armoured_rails

Comment: Post your controller code

Comment: this error has nothing to do with sorcery at all.

Comment: Totally my mistake on this issue. It's been resolved by removing some irrelevant code that was in there due to trying to patch together something from two different tutorials improperly.

Answer (score 0):

As I can see in your repo there is no "set_user" method - not in UsersController, nor in other controllers and models.
And, by the way, "require_login" method is also undefined (at least I can't see it in any file of your app).

**EDIT.** Ok, I've found 'require_login' method in the [Sorcery](https://github.com/NoamB/sorcery#api-summary) API summary (but not the 'set_user' method). So, it seems that your undefined methods are the methods defined in gem "sorcery". It looks like your App knows nothing about this gem. I see you've add it to your Gemfile but have you installed it [in the proper way](https://github.com/NoamB/sorcery#installation)?

Comment: I thought I followed along with the tutorial on the Sorcery page pretty closely. The original tutorial was designed for Rails 3, and my only experience in Rails is really in version 4, so there may be some discrepancies there in terms of protected params and all. I'm really unclear as to where I've gone astray, so if anyone cares to give me a little hand-holding on this issue, I'd really appreciate your time.